# Windows Forms designer with multiple overlapping panels

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

I have inherited a legacy WinForms application that targets a Windows CE device with a very small screen.

It seems that the entire UI, consisting of around 20 different views, is built as a single form, where individual panels are used for each view and they are made visible or hidden according to the context of the application.

I understand that I need to change this design, probably breaking the UI out into a number of UserControls.

However, before I get that far, I'd like to be able to explore and understand what currently exists. Unfortunately, it seems impossible to navigate within this horrendous form in the designer. The foremost layer of controls is visible, but I can't see what's underneath it. I can't imagine how the original developer built this monstrosity, but apparently he found a way.

Is there a simple way to show/hide controls in the designer or otherwise discover the hidden layers and bring them to the front (without breaking the existing functionality)?

Any other suggestions how to move forward from this mess would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sadly the winforms document outline does not support hiding and showing (Opposed to the WPF Document Outline), but you can always just duplicate the page and delete panels in the document Oultine to get an Idea what is going on. (Or delete everything and undo changes later)

Comment: Thanks @Console - that's what I feared. But is there somewhere that I can at least see the control tree in outline form so that I can attempt to replicate its structure using UserControls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deal with a very similar problem every now and than, and the best solution i found (Out of writing a VisualStudio Extension) is to use the Document Outline Window and delete "layers", copy pasting the stuff into the UserControl and undoing the delete.

The Document Outline shows the Visual Tree of the Form. (Sadly it does not support hiding and showing parts of the tree like the WPF Document Outline does)

You can Find the Document Outline Window under Views -> Other Windows -> Document Outline.